# Unable to plot multiple day/values using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot I am trying to plot two lines of values. 
So var0 has values 49,5,20 for "Monday" , "Tuesday" , "Wednesday"
and var1 has values 49,1,20 for "Monday" , "Tuesday" , "Wednesday"

Here is the code :

```
test_data <- data.frame(
var0 = c(49, 5, 20),
var1 = c(49, 1, 10),
days = c("Monday" , "Tuesday" , "Wednesday"))

ggplot(test_data, days)
geom_line(y = var0, colour = "var0")
geom_line(y = var1, colour = "var1")
```

here are the errors :

```
> ggplot(test_data, days)
Error in inherits(mapping, "uneval") : object 'days' not found
> geom_line(y = var0, colour = "var0")
Error in do.call("layer", list(mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat,  : 
  object 'var0' not found
> geom_line(y = var1, colour = "var1")
Error in do.call("layer", list(mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat,  : 
  object 'var1' not found
```

Am I setting up the data correctly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were several mistakes in your code - x and y values should be put inside the `aes()` call and then there was missing `+` sign between `ggplot()` and `geom_line()` calls.

If you need to plot two groups of y values I would suggest, first, melt your data and then plot melted data frame. With melted data you will need only one `geom_line()` call and you can set color for each line according to `variable` that will be shown in legend.

```
library(reshape2)
test_data2<-melt(test_data,id.vars="days")
test_data2
       days variable value
1    Monday     var0    49
2   Tuesday     var0     5
3 Wednesday     var0    20
4    Monday     var1    49
5   Tuesday     var1     1
6 Wednesday     var1    10
ggplot(test_data2,aes(days,value,color=variable,group=variable))+geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, thats seems to work, do you know how to control the ordering of the x axis values ? The default is alphabetical which confidentiality is the natural ordering of Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday.

Comment: To get correct ordering you should use function factor() to set levels= in order you need.